# Cannot install pytorch on AWS Ubuntu 18.04 even with 3 GiB of ram

Tags: ram

I'm trying to install torch for an ML model on an 18.04 Ubuntu t2 medium instance, and it gives me the following error:

`pip3 install torch`

> Collecting torch Downloading [https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/b9/824df420f6abf551e41bbaacbaa0be8321dc104f9f3803051>513844dc310/torch-1.8.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/b9/824df420f6abf551e41bbaacbaa0be8321dc104f9f3803051%3E513844dc310/torch-1.8.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl) (804.1MB) 100% >|████████████████████████████████| 804.1MB 43.5MB/s Killed

I have checked my ram availability and it is in excess of 2500 megabytes, so I'm not sure what's happening. Does anybody know what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The `t2` instances are not well suited for ML as they’ll hit their boost limit in a matter of minutes. Amazon (understandably) recommends their far more expensive instances 

Comment: @matigo damn, didn't know that :( Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, surprisingly with conda i was able to get pytorch down to instance.

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```